# Reading an exported List

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I have exported a list of 2d coordinates as a `List`:

```
Export["F:\\coordinates.dat", coordinates, "List"];
```

You can access the data here: http://pastebin.com/wFSt9DiD

Now I would like to read the coordinates back with:

```
coordinates = Import["F:\\coordinates.dat", "List"];
```

So far this works.

But, when I want to plot the data with `ListPlot` the plot is empty.

When I try `Flatten[coordinates]`, the coordinates remain unchanged.

It seems that the imported data is imported as a text list.

How can I access the data in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the imported "List" objects are all strings,

```
First@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/wFSt9DiD", "List"]
(* "{1057.9074074074074, 1045.9222222222222}" *)
```

So you need to apply `ToExpression` to get them evaluated,

```
ListPlot[ToExpression /@ 
  Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/wFSt9DiD", "List"]]
```

[image]

I think, if possible, you are better off exporting your data as a `"Table"`, and then you won't run into this problem

```
Export["test.dat", 
 ToExpression /@ 
  Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/wFSt9DiD", "List"], "Table"]
```

and the result is [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/ieqin04f).  You can import it without any hassle now:

```
ListPlot[Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/ieqin04f"]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution. How do I have to export the data correctly, so that I do not need to convert them back with `ToExpression`? With mx files only a simple `Import` is sufficient and the data are available.

Comment: @mrz, see the last part, use `"Table"` instead of `"List"`, as in `Export["temp.dat", data, "Table"]`.  Or `Export["temp.m", data]` if you only need to use the data with *Mathematica*